# What does “rc” in .bowerrc, .jshintrc, .csslintrc stand for?

Tags: javascript, bower, mean, jshint

Googled about this question & couldn't find much needed information.

Am new to MEAN world and first came across `.bowerrc` file when i want to locate bower_components into some specified folder other than default location. Later came across `.jshintrc` when i wanted to configure some rules for JSHint tool. I want to know what this `rc` at the end of these files stands for ? Whats the purpose of `rc` files in general perspective ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does “rc” in .bashrc stand for?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3467/what-does-rc-in-bashrc-stand-for)

Comment: What are you asking? Why those files are named `*rc`? Or what they do?

Comment: @Phil thanks man, it was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

`rc` is often used ac a suffix for configuration files. There is no standard for those, it is just convention. I'd advise to simply open these files to see what they do. Beyond that the file is probably documented in the Documentation of whatever they belong to. The files you mentioned configure options for Bower and JSHint respectively.

It is important to note that there isn't one "unified" MEAN stack. Node allows you to pick all the tools you want to use. Just because your boilerplate uses Bower and JSHint, it doesn't mean you have to. Not that those are bad tools, but you should consider learning about them one-by-one before you use them.